# How to get api data using api keys in httparty ruby

Tags: ruby, api, httparty

i have been trying to get the api data using httparty and been doing it like this

```
require 'httparty'

doc = HTTParty.get('http://ip-api.com/php/105.49.23.183')

puts doc['status']
```

The api response is

```
a:14:{s:6:"status";s:7:"success";s:7:"country";s:5:"Kenya";s:11:"countryCode";s:2:"KE";s:6:"region";s:2:"30";s:10:"regionName";s:16:"Nairobi Province";s:4:"city";s:7:"Nairobi";s:3:"zip";s:5:"09831";s:3:"lat";d:-1.25909;s:3:"lon";d:36.7858;s:8:"timezone";s:14:"Africa/Nairobi";s:3:"isp";s:17:"Safaricom Limited";s:3:"org";s:3:"SFC";s:2:"as";s:25:"AS33771 Safaricom Limited";s:5:"query";s:13:"105.49.23.183";}
```

but the output when i run my script is just
`status`
but i need it to return the data responding to the `status` key which is `success`. I can't figure it out how to do this. Initially in python this method works but ruby is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [JSON formatted API](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) endpoint:

```
require 'httparty'
doc = HTTParty.get('http://ip-api.com/json/105.49.23.183')
puts doc['status']
#=> "success"
```

Notice the `json` instead of the `php` in the URL path. The [serialized PHP](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php) endpoint is deprecated anyway.